# using IK constraint on a Motion capture Rig

Tags: animation, rigging, motion-capture

I was wondering if there was any ways I could use IK constraints on a motion capture Rig to modify a bit the legs and arms movements without damaging too much the MoCap animation? (Or constraint a control rig with the motion capture skeleton)

Thanks for your help.